# I don't see a column in Dataframe?

Tags: pandas

I have a dataframe that starts like this.

```
                          bid
                        close
time                         
2016-05-24 00:00:00       NaN
2016-05-24 00:05:00  0.000611
2016-05-24 00:10:00 -0.000244
2016-05-24 00:15:00 -0.000122
```

If I ask for the columns of this dataframe, I don't see the time (index) column?

```
print list(dfESPCTC.columns)

[(u'bid', 'close')]
```

Is the index not part of the columns in pandas? How do I drop it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The index is indeed not part of the columns, it is an index. Not exactly sure what you mean by "drop it", but you can do `dfESPCTC.reset_index()`

Comment: Thanks that is what I thought

Comment: Glad I could help - apologies for the typo in the name of your dataframe, have corrected this in the answer (that's what you get when answering from a phone!)